# smex only works when i invoke it

Tags: init-file

smex won't work without evoking the command.
 When I run `M-x smex` it will work just for that command
If press `M-x` again I will not work,  will have to press `M-x smex` again.

using centos 7.
Here is my `.emacs` file(sorry don't have github), the smex configuration is in bold:

```
enter ;; init.el --- Emacs configuration

;; INSTALL PACKAGES
;; --------------------------------------

(require 'package)

(add-to-list 'package-archives
       '("melpa" . "http://melpa.org/packages/") t)
(package-initialize)

(defvar myPackages
  '(better-defaults
    elpy ;; add the elpy package
    flycheck ;; add the flycheck package
    material-theme))
(elpy-enable)

;; realtime python checking
(when (require 'flycheck nil t)
  (setq elpy-modules (delq 'elpy-module-flymake elpy-modules))
  (add-hook 'elpy-mode-hook 'flycheck-mode))



(mapc #'(lambda (package)
    (unless (package-installed-p package)
      (package-install package)))
      myPackages)

;; BASIC CUSTOMIZATION
;; --------------------------------------

(setq inhibit-startup-message t) ;; hide the startup message
(load-theme 'solarized-dark t) ;; load material theme
(global-linum-mode t) ;; enable line numbers globally

(require 'ido)
    (ido-mode t)

**(require 'smex)
(smex-initialize)**

;; setting up python
;; install elpy

;; init.el ends here


(custom-set-variables
 ;; custom-set-variables was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
)


(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.

 '(default ((t (:inherit nil :stipple nil :background "#002b36" :foreground "#839496" :inverse-video nil :box nil :strike-through nil :overline nil :underline nil :slant normal :weight normal :height 105 :width normal :foundry "unknown" :family "VL Gothic"))))

 '(font-lock-comment-face ((t (:foreground "#3f7f5f"))))

 '(org-level-1 ((t (:inherit variable-pitch :foreground "#cb4b16" :height 1.03))) t)

 '(org-level-2 ((t (:inherit variable-pitch :foreground "#859900" :height 1.02))) t)

 '(org-level-3 ((t (:inherit variable-pitch :foreground "#268bd2" :height 1.01))) t)

 '(org-level-4 ((t (:inherit variable-pitch :foreground "#b58900" :height 1.01))) t))

(require 'undo-tree)
(global-undo-tree-mode)
```

Comment: You have to add a key binding, see https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Smex

Comment: Welcome to Emacs.SE!  Could you please edit your post to remove the parts of your init file that are not relevant to the question about `smex`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>M-x</kbd> is a key, which runs the command `execute-extended-command` by default. If you want it to run the command `smex`, you need to bind it to `smex` by yourself, for example,

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-x") 'smex)
```